# Permission denied when creating new directories, downloading and copying files. How do I give permissions to these trivial tasks?

Tags: permissions, lubuntu

I've been using Lubuntu for a couple of months now and I've never come across this kind of difficulty. I reinstalled Lubuntu yesterday and I find myself using `sudo` for almost anything: copying and downloading files, creating directories, etc.

I don't think it's possible to find a *permissions* option in one of openbox's menus. I don't know how to search for this problem in the internet either.

Is there a way (command (?)) to grant permission(s) to some (or all of some kind) tasks once and for all?

Thanks!

Comment: Most permissions issues, at least in my experience, are the result of a user using `sudo` to run GUI and other applications, then changing settings/configs/etc and thus taking permissions away from themselves, and giving the ownership to root (ie. change was made whilst using `sudo` and not as the user themselves). My guess is you used `sudo` for things you shouldn't have, made changes (in program settings) when using `sudo` (and not as you) thus now require `sudo`. You've given no specifics, but a look for files in your $HOME (user dir) not owned by you (but root) may help, or give details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This often happens on a multi-user computer. On installing fresh OS, UID of all users change if not added in the same order as previous. You can verify this by

```
cd /home
ls -lh

drwxr-xr-x 68 1002  1002   4.0K Aug 18 23:10 username
```

Note the old UID, 1002 in this case

Now check your existing UID

```
id

uid=1000(username) gid=1000(username) ...
```

New UID is 1000. **If the two UIDs differ** run this command.

```
cd /home
sudo chown -R username:username username
```

UIDs increment with each addition of new user.

Comment: In fact, this is exactly what I did and worked perfectly fine. Thanks for the explanation!